# Set value in dictionary if value not there?

Tags: python

I am using a dictionary to store a bunch of counters where each counter is counting the occurence of a file type (.wav, .mp3, etc).

```
filetypecounter = {}
```

When I come across a certain file type I want to be able to increase a counter in a pythonic way. So I am thinking...

```
filetypecounter[filetype] +=1
```

However, if the filetype is not in the dictionary I want to instantiate it to 1.
So my logic is if filetype counter is there, add 1 to the counter value, else set it to one.

```
if filetype not in filetypecounter:
    filetypecounter[filetype] = 1
else: 
    filetypecounter[filetype] +=1
```

Is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

filetypecounter = defaultdict(int)
filetypecounter[filetype] += 1
```

or

```
from collections import Counter

filetypecounter = Counter()
filetypecounter.update([filetype])
```

For info, if you must use a `dict`, your solution (checking if the key is present) is a reasonable one. Perhaps a more 'pythonic' solution might be:

```
filetypecounter = {}
filetypecounter[filetype] = filetypecounter.get(filetype, 0) + 1
```

Really though, this and other suggestions are just variations o the same theme. I'd use the Counter.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want is [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), or [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for Python 2.7 and up.

Answer (score 2):

Well using `collections.Counter` is well covered in this group of answers, but that may not be the fastest choice.

One older way is this:

```
>>> d={}
>>> for ext in ('.mp3','.mp3','.m4a','.mp3','.wav','.m4a'):
...    d[ext]=d.setdefault(ext,0)+1
... 
>>> d
{'.mp3': 3, '.wav': 1, '.m4a': 2}
```

That is not the fastest either, but it is faster than `collections.Counter`

There are [benchmarks](http://evanmuehlhausen.com/simple-counters-in-python-with-benchmarks/) of these methods and either defaultdict, try/except or your original method are the fastest.

I have reproduced (and expanded) the benchmark here:

```
import urllib2
import timeit

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7p3uycAz')
hamlet = response.read().replace('\r\n','\n')
LETTERS = [w for w in hamlet]
WORDS = hamlet.split(' ')
fmt='{:>20}: {:7.4} seconds for {} loops'
n=100
print
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = defaultdict(int)
        for k in LETTERS:
            counter[k] += 1 
        """,
        setup="from collections import defaultdict; from __main__ import LETTERS")

print fmt.format("defaultdict letters",t.timeit(n),n)
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = defaultdict(int)
        for k in WORDS:
            counter[k] += 1 
        """,
        setup="from collections import defaultdict; from __main__ import WORDS")

print fmt.format("defaultdict words",t.timeit(n),n)
print

# setdefault
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = {}
        for k in LETTERS:
            counter[k]=counter.setdefault(k, 0)+1
        """,
        setup="from __main__ import LETTERS")
print fmt.format("setdefault letters",t.timeit(n),n)
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = {}
        for k in WORDS:
            counter[k]=counter.setdefault(k, 0)+1
        """,
        setup="from __main__ import WORDS")
print fmt.format("setdefault words",t.timeit(n),n)
print

# Counter
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="c = Counter(LETTERS)",
        setup="from collections import Counter; from __main__ import LETTERS")

print fmt.format("Counter letters",t.timeit(n),n)
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="c = Counter(WORDS)",
        setup="from collections import Counter; from __main__ import WORDS")
print fmt.format("Counter words",t.timeit(n),n)
print

# in
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = {}
        for k in LETTERS:
            if k in counter: counter[k]+=1
            else: counter[k]=1   
        """,
        setup="from __main__ import LETTERS")
print fmt.format("'in' letters",t.timeit(n),n)
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = {}
        for k in WORDS:
            if k in counter: counter[k]+=1
            else: counter[k]=1   
        """,
        setup="from __main__ import WORDS")
print fmt.format("'in' words",t.timeit(n),n)
print

# try
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = {}
        for k in LETTERS:
            try:
                counter[k]+=1
            except KeyError:
                counter[k]=1     
        """,
        setup="from __main__ import LETTERS")
print fmt.format("try letters",t.timeit(n),n)
t = timeit.Timer(stmt="""
        counter = {}
        for k in WORDS:
            try:
                counter[k]+=1
            except KeyError:
                counter[k]=1             """,
        setup="from __main__ import WORDS")
print fmt.format("try words",t.timeit(n),n)
print "\n{:,} letters and {:,} words".format(len(list(LETTERS)),len(list(WORDS)))
```

Prints:

```
 defaultdict letters:   3.001 seconds for 100 loops
   defaultdict words:  0.8495 seconds for 100 loops

  setdefault letters:   4.839 seconds for 100 loops
    setdefault words:   0.946 seconds for 100 loops

     Counter letters:   7.335 seconds for 100 loops
       Counter words:   1.298 seconds for 100 loops

        'in' letters:   4.013 seconds for 100 loops
          'in' words:  0.7275 seconds for 100 loops

         try letters:   3.389 seconds for 100 loops
           try words:   1.571 seconds for 100 loops

175,176 letters and 26,630 words
```

Personally I was surprised that `try` `except` is one of the fastest ways to do this.  Who knew...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method would be a try / except clause:

```
try: 
    filetypecounter[filetype] += 1
except KeyError:
    filetypecounter[filetype] = 1
```

If you have fewer filetypes than files, this method is more efficient, because instead of unnecessarily checking if the `filetype` is in `filetypecounter`, you assume that this is the case and only create a new entry in `filetypecounter` when it is not.

**Edit**: Added `KeyError` in response to comment from @delnan.

Comment: Bare `except:` is bad because it catches more exceptions than sensible, hiding bugs (in this case, an example of a bug that might be hidden is a typo in `filetypecounter` or `filetype`, or the dictionary containing values that can't be incremented).

Comment: Thanks @delnan, answer duly modified.

Answer (score 1):

I guess all you need is [counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module.

Answer (score 1):

The [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) class does exactly what you (really) need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
d['foo'] += 1
# d['foo'] is now 1
```

Another idea is to use `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
d.setdefault('foo', 0)  # won't override if 'foo' is already in d
d['foo'] += 1
```